# Multiple promises fulfilled and saved in NodeJS

Tags: asynchronous, async-await, promise, callback, es6-promise

I have this part of code that work but strangely the latest step of outputting the result doesn't work.. When i try to log the first element of array it returns **undefined** bacause the execution is asynchronous. I thought to build a series of nested callbacks but **I think that is a bad practice**. Is there any other way to makes it work without create nested promise callbacks?

CODE:

```
  var ImgGalleyURL = [];
  //CONTROLLO SE SONO STATE INSERITE IMMAGINI DA CARICARE E LE CARICO
  if (postwp.postImgGallery1 != null && postwp.postImgGallery1 != "") {
    msg.createMedia(postwp.postImgGallery1).then((imgURL)=>ImgGalleyURL.push(imgURL));
  }
  if (postwp.postImgGallery2 != null && postwp.postImgGallery2 != "") {
    msg.createMedia(postwp.postImgGallery2).then((imgURL)=>ImgGalleyURL.push(imgURL));
  }
  if (postwp.postImgGallery3 != null && postwp.postImgGallery3 != "") {
    msg.createMedia(postwp.postImgGallery3).then((imgURL)=>ImgGalleyURL.push(imgURL));
  }
  if (postwp.postImgGallery4 != null && postwp.postImgGallery4 != "") {
    msg.createMedia(postwp.postImgGallery4).then((imgURL)=>ImgGalleyURL.push(imgURL));
  }
  if (postwp.postImgGallery5 != null && postwp.postImgGallery5 != "") {
    msg.createMedia(postwp.postImgGallery5).then((imgURL)=>ImgGalleyURL.push(imgURL));
  }
  console.log(ImgGalleyURL[0] + "this is the first image loaded");
```

Thank you all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for [`Promise.race`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/race):

```
const promises = [];
for (let i=1; i<=5; i++) {
  const propName = "postImgGallery" + i;
  if (postwp[propName] != null && postwp[propName] != "") {
    promises.push(msg.createMedia(postwp[propName]));
  }
}
Promise.race(promises).then(firstUrl => {
  console.log(firstUrl + "this is the first image loaded");
});
Promise.all(promises).then(imgGalleryURLs => {
  console.log("All images ("+ imgGalleryURLs.join(", ") + ") loaded");
});
```

You were trying to log the first value of the array when none of the promises was fulfilled yet, so it was still empty.

Comment: I am not surprised that you are an ecmascript-6 and promise evangelist, your solutions are so sophisticated. Can you explain me pls why and how the race method works? Promise.race(promises).then(firstUrl => ...

Because the documentation is a mess and I don't understand much. How is race used in this case?